# How do I apply a function with multiple arguments over a list?

Tags: r, lapply

For example, I want to apply the intersect() function to every element (dataset) of a list. I want each element compared to this aother dataset, data1.

I know I can use a for loop, but I was thinking that I could use lapply. However, I need to hold one of the arguments constant. How can I do so?

This doesn't work:

```
> lapply(list(winnepennninckx, brunner), intersect(,selectG))
```

Comment: This is what the `...` does, documented in `?lapply` as "optional arguments to `FUN`". In your case, `lapply(list(winnepennninckx, brunner), intersect, selectG)`

Comment: Does R automatically assume the optional arguments to be apart of the function? If so, how does it decide the order?

Comment: Yes, as documented `...` arguments are passed on to `FUN`. The list you iterate on is the first argument passed to `FUN`, the other arguments will be passed in order. You can name them if you want to be sure, e.g., `lapply(your_list, intersect, y = selectG)`. If you wanted to iterate on the *second* argument of `intersect`, the common way is to do an anonymous function to swap the order: `lapply(your_list, FUN = function(z, x) intersect(x, z), x = selectG)`